# How can we exclude results from users with tty=(none) in auditd?

Tags: linux, tty, linux-audit

### Is there any way to exclude the event records having tty=(none)

I have tried many ways of adding rule but nothing worked out.
This is my current log file:

```
 > > type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1554390377.124:5): arch=40000003 syscall=11
    > > success=yes exit=0 a0=810cf88 a1=810bd88 a2=80f5008 a3=810bd88 items=2
    > > ppid=9991 pid=10497 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0
    > > egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 ses=4294967295 tty=(none) comm="date"
    > > exe="/bin/busybox.nosuid" key=(null)  
    > 
    > > type=EXECVE msg=audit(1554390377.124:5): argc=2 a0="date" a1="+%m%d%y-%H:%M:%S:%N"
    > 
    > > type=CWD msg=audit(1554390377.124:5): cwd="/" type=PATH
    > > msg=audit(1554390377.124:5): item=0 name="/bin/date" inode=1538
    > > dev=b3:03 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL
    > > 
    > > type=PATH msg=audit(1554390377.124:5): item=1 name=(null) inode=969
    > > dev=b3:03 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL
    > 
    > > type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1554390389.524:36): arch=40000003 syscall=11
    > > success=yes exit=0 a0=80f68a8 a1=80f6ae8 a2=80f3008 a3=80f6ae8 items=2
    > > ppid=9906 pid=10592 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0
    > > egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 ses=4294967295 tty=pts0 comm="cat"
    > > exe="/bin/busybox.nosuid" key=(null) 
    > > type=EXECVE
    > > msg=audit(1554390389.524:36): argc=2 a0="cat" a1="/tmp/cpuinfo"
    > > type=CWD msg=audit(1554390389.524:36): cwd="/"
```

I need only the following lines in log file where tty=pts0/pts[any number]:

```
> type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1554390389.524:36): arch=40000003 syscall=11
> success=yes exit=0 a0=80f68a8 a1=80f6ae8 a2=80f3008 a3=80f6ae8 items=2
> ppid=9906 pid=10592 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0
> egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 ses=4294967295 tty=pts0 comm="cat"
> exe="/bin/busybox.nosuid" key=(null) 
> type=EXECVE
> msg=audit(1554390389.524:36): argc=2 a0="cat" a1="/tmp/cpuinfo"
> type=CWD msg=audit(1554390389.524:36): cwd="/"
> type=PATH
> msg=audit(1554390389.524:36): item=0 name="/bin/cat" inode=1538
> dev=b3:03 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL
> type=PATH msg=audit(1554390389.524:36): item=1 name=(null) inode=969
> dev=b3:03 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL
```

Comment: Since you mentioned that you _"... have tried many ways of adding rule but nothing worked out."_ can you share your rules which are working and which not? As also a list of the non working rules?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand [How to exclude specific users or groups when using auditd to watch files](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2482221) and [How to exclude specific users, groups, or services when using auditd to audit syscalls](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2477471), you could exclude specific services and keys by using filters `_F` with not (`!`), i.e.

```
-F subj_type!=SYSCALL
```

and/or

```
-F tty=(none)
```

Maybe you need to add some more specifications.